# Would like to have option to add new item to db or select previous db entry php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Newbie to php/mysql. Would like to have the option of inserting a new location in my form that is then added to the db or choose from a pulldown of locations currently registered in db. Below is my code (that works) to present the pulldown options. Not sure how to add the ability to include new location. I can do either/or (input/text or select/option) but not both in same form. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
......
<p>Location: <select name="e_location">
<?php if (isset($_POST['e_location'])) {echo $_POST['e_location'];
}
?>" />

<?php $q = "SELECT DISTINCT e_location FROM events";
echo '<option selected value="">Choose Previous City/State</option>';
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
if (mysqli_num_rows($r) >= 1) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<option 
value="'.$row['e_location'].'">'.$row['e_location'].'</option>';
}
.....
```

Comment: Sorry, missed the '}?></select></p>' at the bottom when pasting.

Comment: should it be on the same page? or you can have a link to your add new location page

Comment: I'd prefer not to do it that way. Possibly JQuery or something of that nature is the answer but I'm really clueless there.